# Does the limit $ \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \sin(x)^{\frac{1}{\cos x}} $ exist?

Tags: limits

Does the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \sin(x)^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}  $$

exist?

Clearly, it is of the form $1^\infty$
Do you have any analytical solutions or hints?
Also, if the limit exists, how can it be found?

(I am aware of the solution which uses simplification by natural log. If you have something more related to that, do add it)

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac {\ln (\sin x)} {\cos x}$.

Comment: I was looking for some alternate method. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using continuity of the logarithm and exponential,

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}^{1/\cos x}=\lim_{t\to0}((1-t^2)^{1/t^2})^{t/2}=\left(\lim_{t\to0}(1-t^2)^{1/t^2}\right)^{\lim_{t\to0}t/2}=e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the limit is evaluable. As you pointed out, it is in the $1^{\infty}$ form, so we have:
$$L=e^{\lim_{x\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\ln \sin x}{\cos x}}$$
Since the limit is now in $\frac 00$ form, L'Hôpital rule is applicable.
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\ln \sin x}{\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=0$$
Hence $L=e^0=1$.